# php - Simplify select from multidimensional array according the preferred group of row values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

On output, I want an array with **row per unique height**. If there is row with same `ext` and `height` (like in 0, 6) on input, just take the first value. If there are rows with the same `height` prefer `jpg` over `png` over `gif` over the rest (3, 9, 10).

This is the input array:

```
[input] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg
                [height] => 800
                [md5] => 87167a1952911df64a3b1a423c95b32b
                [id] => ddf
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ext] => png
                [height] => 330
                [md5] => 87167a1952911df64a3b1a423c95b32b
                [id] => 117
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg
                [height] => 330
                [md5] => 8d167a1952ds1df64a3b1a423c95b32b
                [id] => 24
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [ext] => gif
                [height] => 150
                [md5] => 4a4d993ed7bd7d467b27af52d2aaa800
                [id] => 68
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg
                [height] => 1024
                [md5] => 912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570
                [id] => 78
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [ext] => png
                [height] => 1024
                [md5] => 6a204bd89f3c8348afd5c77c717a097a
                [id] => lp
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg
                [height] => 800
                [md5] => dce4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
                [id] => cd
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [ext] => png
                [height] => 800
                [md5] => ace4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
                [id] => mmc
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [ext] => png
                [height] => 430
                [md5] => gce4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
                [id] => 115
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [ext] => png
                [height] => 150
                [md5] => xce4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
                [id] => 4568
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg
                [height] => 150
                [md5] => cce4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
                [id] => 8777
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [ext] => gif
                [height] => 400
                [md5] => kke4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
                [id] => 877
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [ext] => bmp
                [height] => 500
                [md5] => 89e4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
                [id] => 857
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg // no height row
                [md5] => rde4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
                [id] => a57
            )
```

This is my ugly code so far:

```
foreach ($input as $row) {
    if (!empty($row['height'])) {
        $vo['height'] = $row['height'];
        $vo['md5'] = $row['md5'];
        $vo['ext'] = $row['ext'];
        $help_array[$row['height']][$row['ext']][] = $vo; // creates help array grouped by height
    }
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($help_array as $helps) {
    foreach ($helps as $k => $help) {
        if ($k == 'jpg') { // best format to use
            $output[$i] = $help[0];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (empty($output[$i])) { // if still empty use png
        foreach ($helps as $k => $help) {
            if ($k == 'png') {
                $output[$i] = $help[0];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (empty($output[$i])) { // if there is no jpg or png take gif
        foreach ($helps as $k => $help) {
            if ($k == 'gif') {
                $output[$i] = $help[0];
                break;
            } else { // or take what left
                $output[$i] = $help[0];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    ++$i;
}
print_r($output);
```

It has toooo many lines :-) This should be the output array (optionally without `ext` column as it's not required anymore) sorted by `height`:

```
[output] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg
                [height] => 150
                [md5] => cce4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
            )


        [1] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg
                [height] => 330
                [md5] => 8d167a1952ds1df64a3b1a423c95b32b
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ext] => gif
                [height] => 400
                [md5] => kke4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [ext] => png
                [height] => 430
                [md5] => gce4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [ext] => bmp
                [height] => 500
                [md5] => 89e4f98878b0c302cb3de0dcd27d8bc8
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg
                [height] => 800
                [md5] => 87167a1952911df64a3b1a423c95b32b
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [ext] => jpg
                [height] => 1024
                [md5] => 912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570
            )
```

Comment: And if the `height` is not specified, as in the last entry in input

Comment: If there is no `height` skip the row. See the line `if (!empty($row['height'])) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function that can solve your problem

```
function filterAndSort($input){
    $output = array();
    $extensionsWeght = array(
        'jpg' => 0,
        'png' => 1,
        'gif' => 2
    );
    foreach ($input as $v) {
        //Edit 1:  skip if no hieght is present
        if(!isset($v['height'])){
            continue;
        }
        if (!isset($output[$v['height']])) {
            //If it's a new height, add it
            $output[$v['height']] = $v;
        } else {
            //else, choose the prefered ext [if they have the same ext, the first entry is already choosen]
            if ($extensionsWeght[$output[$v['height']]['ext']] > $extensionsWeght[$v['ext']]) {
                $output[$v['height']] = $v;
            }
        }
    }
    //Sort the ouput by height key
    // usort($output, function($a, $b) {
    //    return $a['height'] - $b['height'];
    //});

    //Edit 2 :

    //For sorting the array, as it is indexed with the height key,
    // you can use the built in functions to sort it. (ksort for this case)
    ksort($output);

    return array_values($output);
}
```

You can find the test [here](https://3v4l.org/D0Nag)

Comment: instead of using `usort`, use `ksort`. Then remove the keys with `return array_values($output);`

Comment: can you please explain me why?, is it faster ?

Comment: Probably, but it's especially shorter and more simple than using a user defined comparison function.

Comment: 15 necessary lines vs. 37+ lines of my code, awesome!